# jQuery Speed up adding tooltips to table cells according to row and column name

Tags: jquery, html-table, web-performance

I currently use this function to add tooltips to each table cell according to their row name (left-most cell in the row) and column name (value of top-most cell in the column). It works as intended, but it used up a significant amount of scripting time according to Google Chrome DevTools. How do I speed it up?

```js
const add_tooltip = function(context) {
  context.find("th").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("title", $(this).text());
  });

  context.find("td").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("title", $(this).siblings("th").text() + ", " + context.find("thead th").eq($(this).index()).text());
  });
};

add_tooltip($("table"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can cache `context.find("thead th")` into a variable

Comment: In addition to above, if you loop through `tr` then `td`s in that tr you could also cache `$(this).siblings("th")` without needing to use `siblings`.   Also, not just cache `context.find("thead th")` but cache all the thead texts into an array

Comment: As an alternative, you may not *need* all those tooltips (assuming code in question is a much cut-down sample).  Use zebra-striping / newspaper-rows (ie subtly different colours for each row) so that the user can follow the row across.

Comment: Another option: set the tooltips as you build the html (back-end) rather than via javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the new function I've come up with after collecting everyone's feedback. I've tested it and it doesn't seem much slower than including the `title` attribute while constructing the table with `$.append()` (which makes the code quite clunky).

```js
const add_tooltip = function (context) {
    let row_names = [], column_names = [];

    context.find("th").each(function () {
        $(this).attr("title", $(this).text());

        if ($(this).parents("thead").length)
            column_names.push($(this).text());
        else
            row_names.push($(this).text());
    });

    context.find("tbody, tfoot").find("tr").each(function (i) {
        $(this).find("td").each(function (j) {
            $(this).attr("title", `${row_names[i]}, ${column_names[j + 1]}`);
        });
    });
};
```